# OpenGL - How to rotate light source without rotating object at the same time?

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl, sdl-2, opengl-3

I'm doing the learnopengl tutorials and I'm trying one of the exercises in the Basic Lighting tutorial -

> Try to move the light source around the scene over time using either
>   sin or cos.

Although in my case, I'm using SDL which means I can't use the following equations to rotate my light source around:

```
lightPos.x = 1.0f + sin(glfwGetTime()) * 2.0f;
lightPos.y = sin(glfwGetTime() / 2.0f) * 1.0f;
```

Right now, when I rotate my object, my light source rotates with it, however I want my light source to rotate separately from my object. This is what I have in my render loop which handles the rotation of the light and the object:

```
void OpenGLWindow::render()
{

    lightPos.x = 1.0f + sin(SDL_GetTicks()/1000.0f) * 2.0f;
    lightPos.y = sin((SDL_GetTicks()/1000.0f) / 2.0f) * 1.0f;

    glm::mat4 model(1.0f);
    //model = glm::translate(model, lightPos);
    model = glm::rotate(model, lightPos.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    //model = glm::rotate(model, lightPos.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    model = glm::rotate(model, lightPos.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    int modelMatLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "lightMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatLocation, 1, false, &model[0][0]);

    // NOTE: glm::translate/rotate/scale apply the transformation by right-multiplying by the
    //       corresponding transformation matrix (T). IE glm::translate(M, v) = M * T, not T*M
    //       This means that the transformation you apply last, will effectively occur first
    glm::mat4 modelMat(1.0f);
    modelMat = glm::translate(modelMat, parentEntity.position);
    modelMat = glm::rotate(modelMat, parentEntity.rotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    modelMat = glm::rotate(modelMat, parentEntity.rotation.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    modelMat = glm::rotate(modelMat, parentEntity.rotation.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    modelMat = glm::scale(modelMat, parentEntity.scale);
    int modelMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "modelMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLoc, 1, false, &modelMat[0][0]);
}
```

And this is what I have in my vertex shader:

```
in vec3 position;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewingMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 lightMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 transformedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewingMatrix * modelMatrix * lightMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);

    gl_Position = transformedPosition;
    FragPos = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(modelMatrix))) * position;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
out vec4 outColor;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec3 FragPos;

uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform vec3 objectColor;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{
    float ambientStrength = 0.06;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;

    float specularStrength = 0.6;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lightColor;
    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * objectColor;
    outColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

How do I rotate the light source only, without the object rotating also?

Comment: You are setting the model matrix twice, is this intended? What does `lightMatrix` do? It doesn't seem to modify the illumination calculation in any way. In which space is `lightPos` given? From the code, it looks as if the light should stay at the same position when `lightPos` and `viewPos` are given in world space.

Comment: No. I only tried this and I saw that the light would rotate with the object. Otherwise I'm not sure how to make it rotate, is there part of the code related to "lightMatrix" that I should remove?

Comment: The lightMatrix doesn't influence lighting as of now. What you have to do is to transform the `lightPos` with this matrix before setting this uniform. And completely leave away the lightMatrix in the vertex shader. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rotate the lightsource, then you have to transform `lightPos` instead of rotating the model. This is also more efficient because it requires only one matrix transformation per frame (instead of one per vertex). The code should look as follows:

```
// C++
glm::vec4 lightPos(...) // <-- The light position you currently use

glm::mat4 lightM(1.0f);
lightM = glm::rotate(lightM, lightRotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
lightM = glm::rotate(lightM, lightRotation.y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
lightM = glm::rotate(lightM, lightRotation.x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

glm::vec4 rotatedLightPos = lightM * lightPos;

glUniform3f(lightPosLocation, rotatedLightPos.x, rotatedLightPos.y, rotatedLightPos.z);
```

Vertex Shader:

```
// GLSL
in vec3 position;
out vec3 FragPos;
out vec3 Normal;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewingMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec4 transformedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewingMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);

    gl_Position = transformedPosition;
    FragPos = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
    Normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(modelMatrix))) * position;
}
```

The fragment shader stays as it is now.

Comment: I'm sorry but where do you define `lightRotation` that you are using in `lightM = glm::rotate(lightM, lightRotation.z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));`

Comment: This defines how much you want to rotate the lightsource. I guess you already have that somewhere.

Comment: I'm using these to rotate: `lightPos.x = 1.0f + sin(glfwGetTime()) * 2.0f;` and `lightPos.y = sin(glfwGetTime() / 2.0f) * 1.0f;`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. That was completely my fault. In this case, you only have to remove lightMatrix from the vertex shader and everything should be working.

Comment: I get an error here: `glm::vec4 rotatedLightPos = lightM * lightPos;`

`error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘glm::mat4 {aka glm::tmat4x4<float, (glm::precision)0>}’ and ‘glm::vec3 {aka glm::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0>}’)`

Comment: As I said: Since you already have the rotated position, you can leave the whole code black away. But I guess you get the error because `lightPos` is a vec3 in your case. If you only want to rotate (and not translate) you can use `vec3 rotatedLightPos = glm::mat3(lightM) * lightPos;`

Comment: Ok. Fixed that, getting one last error: 

`error: cannot convert ‘glm::vec3 {aka glm::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0>}’ to ‘GLint {aka int}’ in argument passing
  glUniform3f(lightPos, rotatedLightPos.x, rotatedLightPos.y, rotatedLightPos.z);`

Comment: Check my code, please. It says glUniform3f(lightPos**Location**, ...); Thats the uniform location of the the `lightPos` uniform. Why would you pass a vec3 as uniform location?

Comment: Ok. Fixed everything. You can ignore the previous comment.. Seems to work. Thank you very much. :). Sorry being such a bother. Marked your answer as correct.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry again for misreading the question at first.